# android - pound sign being corrupted

Tags: java, android, encoding

I have a routine to pass back a currency sign based on a inputted country code, but the pound sign is being corrupted and I'm not sure why.  Instead of the expected "£" when I pass in `accountCurrency="GBP"`, it's returning "Â£".  What is happening?

```
public static String findCurrencySymbol(String accountCurrency) {
    if (accountCurrency == null || accountCurrency.trim().length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    String curr = accountCurrency.toUpperCase();
    if ("GBP".equals(curr)) {
        return "£";
    } else if ("USD".equals(curr)
            || "AUD".equals(curr)
            || "CAD".equals(curr)
            || "SGD".equals(curr)) {
        return "$";
    } else if ("EUR".equals(curr)) {
        return "€";
    } else {
        // return raw currency code with whitespace attached
        // should lead to display like: "YPY 12440.00"
        return accountCurrency + " ";
    }
}
```

edit: the other values are returning as expected.

Comment: Did you correctly specify the encoding of your `.java` file to whatever you use to compile your source (IDE, build environment, command line compiler, ...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that you copy/pasted the pound sign from some word document along with some non printable characters? I've seen that happen a lot.

What happens if you replace it with the unicode value of the symbol: "\u00A3" ?